# Proper caron accents with kpfonts?

Tags: characters, kpfonts, diacritical-mark

In good typesetting, the caron accent on some letters (t, d, l) should be replaced with something looking more like an apostrophe. This is done correctly with the "default" font with T1 encoding at least:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\Huge

Test \v{s} \v{t} \v{d} \v{l} t' d' l'

\emph{Test \v{s} \v{t} \v{d} \v{l} t' d' l'}

\end{document}
```

[image]
(note the difference with the plain apostrophe)

But with the `kpfonts` package (just uncomment it in the code), it doesn't look good:

[image]

It looks like the caron position is altered (and perhaps even the shape for t), it's still just a caron. With the italic t no attempt is made.

I presume this is just a sign of the right glyphs being missing in the fonts. But is there anything that could be done to make it look better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have uploaded version 0.60 of the `kpfonts-otf` package with corrected glyphs for dcaron, lcaron, tcaron, Lcaron (and small + petites caps variants).

This new version should be available in the main TeX distributions (TeXLive, MikTeX,…) tomorrow or after tomorrow.

I hope these OpenType fonts will now be usable also with the Czech and Slovak languages.  Unfortunately, the legacy version is no longer maintained, it will not be fixed in a foreseeable future…

Comment: Is there anything holding people back from taking over legacy kpfonts? I can see that the fence scaling still have this very large jump between unscaled and `\big`, that is much bigger than for most other fonts.

Comment: It is a large amount of work to take over fonts that you didn't create yourself, specially for kpfonts which have three families (roman, sans ,mono) with eight different weights in Roman and three families in Math (regular, light, sans)!  Imho Type1 fonts have no future, that's  why I built the OpenType version.

Comment: Well, I still think there are a lot more pdflatex users than xe- and lualatex users. And since xe- and lualatex are still much slower, there will still be a lot of pdflatex users.

Comment: Additionally what about the design (in the otf version as well) of `(` vs `\big(`

Answer (score 4):

#### UPDATE November 2023

The problem has been solved for the OpenType version, so the workarounds below are only needed for the legacy Type1 fonts.

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

To my dismay, the same problem is present in the OpenType version. Happily, this version (and perhaps also the legacy one) is actively maintained by Daniel Flipo, so perhaps this can be corrected.

For the time being you can work around the bug:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\v}{\encodingdefault}{d}{d\fixedcaron}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\v}{\encodingdefault}{l}{l\fixedcaron}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\v}{\encodingdefault}{t}{t\fixedcaron}

\newunicodechar{ď}{\v{d}}
\newunicodechar{ľ}{\v{l}}
\newunicodechar{ť}{\v{t}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fixedcaron}{%
  \/%
  \raisebox{0.3ex}{%
    \fontsize{\fpeval{0.8*(\f@size)}}{\z@}\selectfont
    \kern-\fpeval{0.15*(1-\strip@pt\fontdimen1\font)}em '%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test \v{s} \v{t} \v{d} \v{l} ť ď ľ

\textbf{Test \v{s} \v{t} \v{d} \v{l} ť ď ľ}

\textit{Test \v{s} \v{t} \v{d} \v{l} ť ď ľ}

\textbf{\textit{Test \v{s} \v{t} \v{d} \v{l} ť ď ľ}}

\end{document}
```

#### Output with LuaLaTeX

[image]

#### Output with `pdflatex`

[image]

Of course, copy-paste will result in letter+apostrophe.

Comment: A bug report has been filed to the maintainer.

Comment: Thanks for the report. I'll fix this issue for the OpenType version in the next few days. Can  you confirm that the default (Latin Modern) is correct? Then also the capital L should get an apostrophe like accent instead of the caron…

Comment: @DanielFlipo Yes, also the L. You may want to look at the realizations done for the CS fonts, in particular `csr10`: since they were developed by the CS-TUG, they should be considered authoritative.

Comment: Thank you both for the prompt and helpful response. However, the suggested fix is not enough because is doesn't respect kerning/spacing with the next character (compare e.g. "ta" with "ťa").

Comment: @Jellby That's unfortunately expected.